# How to execute QRandomGenerator.global() method

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, pyside2, errno

I'm using spyder.

When I run my code using `QRandomGenerator.global()` method, error is thrown.

Because `global` is a predetermined name.

```
from PySide2 import QtCore
import PySide2
import os, sys


dirname = os.path.dirname(PySide2.__file__)
plugin_path = os.path.join(dirname, 'plugins', 'platforms')
os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = plugin_path
def main():    
    
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv) if QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance() is None else QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()
  
    r = QtCore.QRandomGenerator.global()
    
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Qt functions that are named as reserved keywords in Python (like `QTextDocument.print()` or `QWidget.raise()`) use an underscore suffix.

```
    r = QtCore.QRandomGenerator.global_()
```